# How to load the page before the events?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I am working on this C# page but I don't know how to format it properly.

1/ I want to add header logo and footer text right before and after the result of query string. I'm not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

When I execute the code, the query string result appears before the logo and the footer.

2/ My second question is how to store the value of Response.Write in a variable and display it on .aspx page? I want to format the result, put them in nice table layout and such.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Error.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        string ErrorCode = Request.QueryString["ErrorCode"];
        if (ErrorCode != null)
        {
            Response.Write("ErrorCode: " + ErrorCode + "</br>");
        }

        string ErrorName = Request.QueryString["ErrorName"];
        if (ErrorName != null)
        {
            Response.Write("ErrorName: " + ErrorName + "</br>");
        }

        string ErrorMessage = Request.QueryString["ErrorMessage"];
        if (ErrorMessage != null)
        {
            Response.Write("ErrorMessage: " + ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Error.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-logo">
            <img alt="Logo" src="images/main-logo.jpg" />
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">                 
    </form>

    <div class="footer">
            <img alt="Footer" src="images/footer.jpg" />
    </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

This is my new code after fixing it with everyone's help:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{ 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        string ErrorCode = Request.QueryString["ErrorCode"];
        if (ErrorCode != null)
        {
            lbErrorCode.Text = "ErrorCode: " + ErrorCode ;
        }

        string ErrorName = Request.QueryString["ErrorName"];
        if (ErrorName != null)
        {
            lbErrorName.Text = "ErrorName: " + ErrorName;
        }

        string ErrorMessage = Request.QueryString["ErrorMessage"];
        if (ErrorMessage != null)
        {
            lbErrorMessage.Text = "ErrorMessage: " + ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Error.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="main-logo">
                <img alt="Logo" src="images/logo.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div><asp:Label ID="lbErrorCode" runat="server" /> </div>
            <div><asp:Label ID="lbErrorName" runat="server" /></div>
            <div><asp:Label ID="lbErrorMessage" runat="server" /></div>
</form>
```

When I execute the page without any value, the logo loaded nicely, but when I pass some sample data: /?ErrorMessage=HelloWorld&ErrorCode=500&ErrorName=InvalidInput then the logo doesn't load.

Any idea please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `Response.Write`.  Use an `<asp:Label>` or `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control or something..

Comment: Is this something like label.Text=Request.Querystring["ABC"] ?

Comment: Just added an example below.  If you're not familiar with ASP.NET controls and page lifecycle, you'll probably want to find a basic ASP.NET tutorial and get familiar with the overall concept.  Also, ASP.NET is kinda dead (or at least dying), so unless there's a specific reason you're learning it, it might be better to go with the ASP.NET MVC framework.

Comment: `Response.Write` writes directly to the response, which means you have little control over where the output gets written to.

Comment: @MikeChristensen Correction, Web Forms is kinda dead. ASP.NET as a whole is fine. ASP.NET includes Web Forms, MVC, Web Pages, SignalR etc.

Comment: @mason - Excellent point, thanks for the clarification..

Comment: @MikeChristensen I fixed the code, but there is one issue, the image doesn't load when the page gets value from query string. The image displays when there is no value from query string. I'm not sure why...

Comment: Hmm I'm stumped.  I don't see anything wrong.  Can you post the actual HTML ("View Source" in the browser) for both the working and non-working request?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: I think I found the error, but I'm not sure why it's error. When I add "/" into src in the image tag, it works for both null value and sample data value (src="/images/logo.jpg). If it's just src="images/cdph-logo.jpg then the image just load with null value from query string. I really don't know why. It should be error out consistently, but it's not. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yea that is *very* odd (could be a Stack Overflow question in itself)..  Either way, it's usually best to fully qualify URLs at least relative to the server root anyway..

Answer (score 1):

My ASP.NET WebForms is a bit rusty, so hopefully this will get you started.

First, you'll want to use an ASP.NET Label control to represent your text, rather than using `Response.Write` (which will just dump text out to the response buffer at whatever point it happens to be at the time).  Try adding a Label control to your page:

```
<div class="main-logo">
   <img alt="Logo" src="images/main-logo.jpg" />
   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

You can then set the `Text` property in your code behind:

```
if (ErrorCode != null)
{
   Label1.Text = "ErrorCode: " + ErrorCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: Question please. I fixed the code as you showed me, I posed it above. When I pass some value into query string the image is not loaded, but when I just execute, no query value, then the logo loaded nicely. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: In my example above, the image is hard coded and will always show up.  Can you edit your question to show your new code, both HTML and C#?

Comment: @MikeChistensen: I edited my question and showed new code. After I execute the page, the logo's loaded nicely. Then I manually add /?ErrorCode=100&ErrorMessage=TestMessage&ErrorName=TestErrror then only the value show up, the logo is not showed up

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to use `Response.Write`? If not, you can put a label inside form1 and pass the error message to the label's Text property.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">    
<asp:Label id="lblError" runat="server"></asp:Label>             
</form>
```

and in the `Page_Load`

```
...
    string ErrorCode = Request.QueryString["ErrorCode"];
            if (ErrorCode != null)
            {
                lblError.Text=Label1.Text+"ErrorCode: " + ErrorCode;
            }
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it now.

Comment: You can even set style to the label (for example, `<asp:Label id="lblError" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Response.Write to do this kind of stuff.  Instead, place an ASP:Literal control anywhere on the page you want to implement text.  Then set the Literal's Text property to the string you want to display.

**ALSO - DO NOT WRITE TEXT FROM A QUERYSTRING DIRECTLY TO THE PAGE**

Make sure you run them through Server.HtmlEncode first, or your page is open to all kinds of XSS vulnerabilities.

Your page should look something like this...

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-logo">
        <img alt="Logo" src="images/main-logo.jpg" />
    </div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">      
      **<ASP:Literal runat="server" id="ltlErrorMessage" />** 
</form>

<div class="footer">
        <img alt="Footer" src="images/footer.jpg" />
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

And the code should be something like:

```
string ErrorCode = Request.QueryString["ErrorCode"];
    if (ErrorCode != null)
    {
        ltlErrorMessage.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(ErrorCode);
    }
```

Comment: thank you. I fixed the code, but when I executed the code, passing some sample value in query string, the image doesn't load. It's load when there is no value in query string. Do you have any idea why?